# Curl connect-timeout and max-time option value changes when I look at libcurl code. Why and what does it represent?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, connection-timeout

I was playing around with the curl command and looking at corresponding lib curl code when i noticed the following :

My command :

```
curl --max-time 1 --connect-timeout 1 -H "User-Agent: ikandaswamy" https://api.github.com/users/ikandaswamy/repos --libcurl newtext
```

newtext

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000L);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.43.0");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 1000L);
```

If you see above, the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS are both 1000 (long). From the man curl I see that the timeout is in seconds. Why is it converted to 1000 ?

Answer (score 0):

The `_MS` suffix on the option names is the clue! It stands for milliseconds, so one second becomes 1000 milliseconds...

Incidentally, this fact is also documented in the [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.html) and [CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS.html) man pages!

While the `--connect-timeout` option accepts seconds, it also accepts seconds specified as a decimal number including fractions of a second like `2.347` seconds and in order to pass that precision on to libcurl it uses the millisecond option version.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason that it uses _MS instead of just CURLOPT_TIMEOUT by default ? since the documentation says that timeout is in seconds.

Comment: The documentation for what? CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS are two different options that take different input. The first one seconds, the latter milliseconds. Again, as documented.

Comment: The documentation for the option --connect-timeout says --connect-timeout SECONDS  Maximum time allowed for connection. So I would expect the generated lib curl to use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in its code. However it used _MS instead. I was wondering why.

Comment: To support fractions of seconds and for simplicity, I updated the answer slightly.